# Search an element from a parsed JSON string array in google apps script

Tags: arrays, json, google-apps-script, webhooks

I have this Google Apps Script bound to a sheet and published as a web app which is acting as a webhook to collect data. This works well and collects the first two results in the script (Insert the data into the sheet) just fine. Time and the complete data package into columns 1 and 3 respectively.

```
function doPost(e) {

var jsonString = e.postData.getDataAsString();
var event = JSON.parse(jsonString)
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Data");
var timeStamp = new Date();
var time = Utilities.formatDate(timeStamp, "BST", "dd/MM/yyyy, h:mm a");
var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();

//Insert the data into the sheet  
sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 1).setValue(time); 
sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 3).setValue(event["data"]);
sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 6).setValue(data.reference);
}
```

The information that is retrieved from the webhook in column 3 is in this format once parsed but I'm struggling to Search for an element in this parsed JSON string array using google apps script and was hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

```
{processing={acquirer_reference_number=24022122407531018095, acquirer_transaction_id=57631018089}, id=pay_n4m745lnx7uy2tmgx4z26mksi, action_id=act_qqno6t6jctdkzbuk2fu3js71e, response_summary=Approved, metadata={is_supplementary=True, ps_id=9, token=tok_war7hee5nole7d21bknt45dm, transaction=7125, hash=84c478fdfbdb2515d46542adbd6ggd516dc0048fd67, order_id=83245142, sandbox=0}, amount=271.0, processed_on=2022-09-21T13:35:32Z, response_code=10000, currency=USD, reference=2694931}
```

I'd really like to search for these three elements within the data and return them into columns 4, 5 and 6 respectively. The order in which these appear seems to be random, so I cannot rely on an index:

1. amount=271.0
2. reference=2694931
3. is_supplementary=True

You can see I've attempted to use dot notation and I've also tried bracket notation but to no avail.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Have you tried running in debug mode and checking at your variables in the viewer to the right of your code? That usually gives some big clues as to the structure of the data.

Comment: Yes, I tried this but I only see this

Comment: Error 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'postData' of undefined
doPost @ Code.gs:3

Comment: There's something wrong with that Json. Even if you paste it into some other reader, it's not in the proper structur.  Use http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/ and compare your pull with a standard json such as https://pastebin.com/raw/3FJaqdJC

Comment: That's strange, I'm collecting this from a payment gateway but I have no control over the structure.  Are you aware of performing a search on a string regardless of its structure to retrieve a result. Perhaps regex extract?

Comment: Your data string is not in JSON format

Comment: Once you get the the JSON correct your data will be extracted with `event.amount`,`event.reference` and `event.is_supplementary`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the input is definitely not JSON, and trying to convert it looks pretty tough. I think regex would be the easier way. Here's a sample that worked with your input:

```js
function doPost(e) {

  var notJsonString = e.postData.contents;
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Data");
  var timeStamp = new Date();
  var time = Utilities.formatDate(timeStamp, "BST", "dd/MM/yyyy, h:mm a");
  var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow()+1;

  //Insert the data into the sheet  
  sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1).setValue(time);
  sheet.getRange(nextRow, 4).setValue(extractAfter("amount=", notJsonString));
  sheet.getRange(nextRow, 5).setValue(extractAfter("reference=", notJsonString));
  sheet.getRange(nextRow, 6).setValue(extractAfter("is_supplementary=", notJsonString));
}

function extractAfter(str, source){
  var regex= new RegExp(`(?<=(${str}))[^,}\s]*`)
  return regex.exec(source)[0]
}
```

Here's the result after sending a POST to the WebApp:

[image]

The regex `(?<=(your_string))[^,}\s]*` is a [lookbehind](https://javascript.info/regexp-lookahead-lookbehind#lookbehind) and it matches any string after the `your_string` pattern and before a `,`, a `}` or a whitespace. Based on the JSON-like format of your input this *should* get the right value no matter where it is generated, but you may run into issues if you want to get a value that does include one of the excluded characters.

As a bonus, your original code was failing at the JSON parse since the input could not be parsed to JSON, but this code would have worked if it had been valid:

```
function doPost(e) {

  var jsonString = e.postData.contents;
  var event = JSON.parse(jsonString)
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Data");
  var timeStamp = new Date();
  var time = Utilities.formatDate(timeStamp, "BST", "dd/MM/yyyy, h:mm a");
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();

  //Insert the data into the sheet  
  sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 1).setValue(time);
  sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 4).setValue(event.amount);
  sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 5).setValue(event.reference);
  sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 6).setValue(event.metadata.is_supplementary);
}
```

And this is what valid JSON would have looked like:

```
{"processing":{"acquirer_reference_number":24022122407531018095, "acquirer_transaction_id":57631018089}, "id":"pay_n4m745lnx7uy2tmgx4z26mksi", "action_id":"act_qqno6t6jctdkzbuk2fu3js71e", "response_summary":"Approved", "metadata":{"is_supplementary":"True", "ps_id":9, "token":"tok_war7hee5nole7d21bknt45dm", "transaction":7125, "hash":"84c478fdfbdb2515d46542adbd6ggd516dc0048fd67", "order_id":83245142, "sandbox":0}, "amount":271.0, "processed_on":"2022-09-21T13:35:32Z", "response_code":10000, "currency":"USD", "reference":2694931}
```

And formatted:

```
{
   "processing":{
      "acquirer_reference_number":24022122407531018095,
      "acquirer_transaction_id":57631018089
   },
   "id":"pay_n4m745lnx7uy2tmgx4z26mksi",
   "action_id":"act_qqno6t6jctdkzbuk2fu3js71e",
   "response_summary":"Approved",
   "metadata":{
      "is_supplementary":"True",
      "ps_id":9,
      "token":"tok_war7hee5nole7d21bknt45dm",
      "transaction":7125,
      "hash":"84c478fdfbdb2515d46542adbd6ggd516dc0048fd67",
      "order_id":83245142,
      "sandbox":0
   },
   "amount":271.0,
   "processed_on":"2022-09-21T13:35:32Z",
   "response_code":10000,
   "currency":"USD",
   "reference":2694931
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, Daniel; however, when I try the code you suggested, I only get the date returned in column 1?

Comment: Did you try the first block or the second one? What does the POST data look like?

Comment: do you have any thoughts or suggestions based on my answer below?

Comment: In your new sample `amount` is under `data`, so you should use `setValue(jsonString.data.amount)` instead. You can visualize it better if you check it out in a [JSON formatter](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/). It's good to see that you were able to generate JSON, though it is strange that the structure changed. You may want to test further since what also changed from your original sample was `metadata` to `data`. If the structure and naming of the JSON is unpredictable you still may be better off using regex, though you'd have to change the "=" to : among other changes.

Comment: I suggest you test to make sure that the JSON remains consistent to determine whether or not you need regex instead.

Comment: Everything is working now, and I can collect the necessary elements. Thank you so much for your help and guidance @daniel, it is very much appreciated : )

I'll post the final Google Apps Script below for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Daniel

I've modified the GAS now, and subsequently, I am retrieving the post in JSON now, see below, but I still cannot collect an element from it. I would like to get a value in column 4, but dot notation doesn't appear to be working.

```
function doPost(e) {
  var jsonString = e.postData.getDataAsString();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Import");
  var timeStamp = new Date();
  var time = Utilities.formatDate(timeStamp, "GMT", "dd/MM/yyyy, h:mm a");
  var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow()+1;

  //Insert the data into the sheet  
  sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1).setValue(time);
  sheet.getRange(nextRow, 3).setValue(jsonString);
  sheet.getRange(nextRow, 4).setValue(jsonString.amount);
}
```

This is the post data received in JSON format:

```
{"id":"evt_l4wuy3s85ieqko2jyd5ndrakfa","type":"payment_captured","created_on":"2022-09-23T09:44:15Z","data":{"action_id":"act_vcmb5fho27l2d7yf54i7uggggy","response_code":"10000","response_summary":"Approved","amount":2980,"metadata":{"sandbox":"0","hash":"3dd6w92a99eaf5ef045e5f1d702b73dg0983b060","card_token":"tok_vd65f37ss5sejf5lshlbiaklve","ps_id":"9","order_id":"55300847","transaction":"6720","is_supplementary":"False"},"processing":{"acquirer_transaction_id":"87543695702","acquirer_reference_number":"24023212166085436959085"},"id":"pay_a47jsqd5gj6kxerj33xjwarwai","currency":"GBP","processed_on":"2022-09-23T09:44:15Z","reference":"2698535"},"_links":{"self":{"href":"https://api.paygateway.com/events/evt_k4wuy3sf6ieejo2jye5jdrak6a"},"payment":{"href":"https://api.paygateway.com/payments/pay_a4cjsqs6la6kxerj33xjws2wai"}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the final Google Apps Script that is bound to a sheet and published as a web app which acts as a webhook to collect data.

This works well and collects the data from the JSON payload. I can access elements from the JSON payload and set the value in a specific cell in a Google Sheet.

I was previously using Zapier to process this as a webhook, but the sheer volume of tasks was getting excessive, so using this method should be better and cheaper!

I hope someone finds this useful in the future.

```
function doPost(e) {

  var jsonString = e.postData.getDataAsString();
  var event = JSON.parse(jsonString)
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Import");
  var timeStamp = new Date();
  var time = Utilities.formatDate(timeStamp, "GMT+1", "dd/MM/yyyy, h:mm a");
  var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow()+1;

  //Insert the data into the sheet  
  sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1).setValue(time);
  sheet.getRange(nextRow, 3).setValue(jsonString);
  sheet.getRange(nextRow, 4).setValue(event.data.amount);
  sheet.getRange(nextRow, 5).setValue(event.data.metadata.is_supplementary);
  sheet.getRange(nextRow, 6).setValue(event.data.reference);
}
```